# Upload to private directory

Tags: 8, files, .htaccess, configuration

I'm trying to setup a private folder for part of the files I need to make available in my Drupal 8 install and I'm having some trouble.

My public files are being served with no problem in `sites/default/files`. In this path, I also have a `private` folder (`sites/default/files/private`), which correctly shows up in Config -> media (not in **red**).

I have setup the .htaccess file for the public `files` root as indicated [here](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2013-003) for Drupal 7, and in the `private` root the same, but adding `Deny from all` at the bottom.

Now when I try to create some content with a file field that is set to private, is says that **the file could not be uploaded** and the message log shows:

> The upload directory private://2016-06 for the file field field_myfieldname could not be created or is not accessible. A newly uploaded file could not be saved in this directory as a consequence, and the upload was canceled.

But the `2016-06` directory is showing up, although empty.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Apparently this was a permissions issue and it's solved.